# ¿Cómo segmentar una imagen respecto a un borde en python?

Tags: python

Necesito segmentar esta imagen y solo obtener el área afectada, he intentado muchas cosas pero no he encontrado la solución, hay alguna forma de segmentar una imagen respecto al borde que tenga?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def reconocerArea(mask, color):
    contornos, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for c in contornos:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)

        if area > 3000:
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            if (M["m00"] == 0): M["m00"] = 1
            cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, color, 3)

img = cv2.imread('quemadura1.jpg')

cv2.imshow('Imagen Original', img)
segGrad00 = np.array([0, 100, 60], np.uint8)
segGrad01 = np.array([5, 255, 255], np.uint8)
segGrad02 = np.array([20, 100, 20], np.uint8)
segGrad03 = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

imageHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

maskSegGrad1 = cv2.inRange(imageHSV, segGrad00, segGrad01)
maskSegGrad2 = cv2.inRange(imageHSV, segGrad02, segGrad03)
maskSegGrad = cv2.add(maskSegGrad1, maskSegGrad2)

reconocerArea(maskSegGrad, (0, 0, 255))
cv2.imshow('Area Afectada', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Adjunto el código que tengo hasta el momento.

Comment: Bienvenido ELIAS SAMUEL TANTALEAN GIL a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, la idea es que la comunidad te ayuda a partir de dónde has llegado.